# How to setup CloudFront url for AWS S3 provider in Strapi

Tags: amazon-s3, strapi

I have installed `strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3` and uploaded file to s3 successfully but is there any way we can change the link to cloudfront instead of using s3 ?

```
strapi": "3.0.0",
"strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3": "^3.0.0",
```

config/plugins.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  upload: {
    accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxxx",
    region: "xxxxx",
    params: {
      Bucket: "xxxxx",
    },
    cloudfrontIsEnabled: 'Yes',
    cloudfrontURL: "xxx.cloudfront.net",
  }
}); (edited)
```

Found old [issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3218) but no luck in the new version

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible with current version of strapi and `strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3`

Your best bet is to fork the provider code, change the url here:
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3/lib/index.js#L38

and add forked provider to your package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
  ...,
  "strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3": "git+https://github.com/<YOUR_GITHUB_ACCOUNT>/strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3.git"
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is actually a good workaround! But probably one may as well create a fork that takes care of other minor details like a button that cleans CloudFront's cache

Comment: You could also try this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3-cloudfront